# Is there such a concept as "pseudo implementation" in software development?

Tags: design, programming-practices, concepts, pseudocode

I'm looking for a label to  describe the practice of using human-based computation methods or other means of "faking" an algorithm for the sake of getting a product or demo off the ground quickly without spending the time to develop an technical/scalable/analytical solution? Eg: using Amazon Turk to count the number of empty tables in a restaurant.

I'm also looking to learn more about this subject, but not sure what to search for. Human-based computation is only one method, I'm interested in the general idea of pseudo-implementation. Any ideas, recommended reading?

Comment: Or to take another well known use case, using child laborers in third world countries to break captchas instead of breaking the captchas programmatically?

Comment: I think the term *"mocking"* pretty well fits what you are describing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is called *Wizard of Oz prototyping*.

Wizard of Oz prototyping is a popular approach in HCI to evaluate new human-computer interfaces. It is typically used if a system is expensive to build but can be easily faked by a human sitting in the other room. Thus the name.

Comment: Interesting, had honestly never heard that name before.

Comment: So this technique may have originated in the field of HCI? I guess the term "Mechanical Turk" from which Amazon Turk gets it's name, refers to the fake 18th Century chess playing machine. I think a Wizard of Oz prototyping icon should be designed to be displayed on websites using this method. Rather than being associated with deception, I think the technique should become more widely promoted as a prototyping tool

Comment: "PAY NO ATTENTION TO THE MILLIONS OF PEOPLE BEHIND THE CURTAIN!"

Answer (score 4):

A well-known example of this sort of problem is the [Mechanical Turk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Turk), where a person hid inside and controlled what otherwise appeared to be a chess-playing machine. *Mechanical Turk* the most widely-used term for it that I've encountered, even though I think I like akuhn's suggestion of *Wizard of Oz prototyping* as a more evocative and easier-to-explain name.

Comment: The term _Spike_ is used to describe quickly developed proofs-of-concept involving non-production-ready systems. A (design) spike usually includes either mocking up other parts of the system or low-quality implementations of them, in order to explore the design of the feature you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this would be related to **crowdsourcing**; just minus the public aspect. You might want to include that in your keyword search.